# Mongodb Positional Operator isn't matching

Tags: mongodb

I have to be missing some small detail here. My goal is to update ALL activities **Not Equal** to `ObjectId("5e3e3c046e76599afe96d50f")`

I am trying to do the following query:

```js
db.getCollection("projects").updateMany(
    {
        "activities._id": { $ne: ObjectId("5e3e3c046e76599afe96d50f") }
    },
    {
        $set: { "activities.$.totalPointsPossible": 5 }
    })
```

and I get the following error:

```js
WriteError({

    "index" : 0,

    "code" : 2,

    "errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.",

    "op" : {

        "q" : {

            "activities._id" : {

                "$ne" : ObjectId("5e3e3c046e76599afe96d50f")

            }

        },

        "u" : {

            "$set" : {

                "activities.$.totalPointsPossible" : 5

            }

        },

        "multi" : true,

        "upsert" : false

    }

})
```

However, if I do this query:

```js
db.getCollection("projects").find({ "activities._id": { $ne: ObjectId("5e3e3c046e76599afe96d50f") } })
```

I get the expected returned documents. I am not sure entirely how `.find()` is matching the `_id` fields for `activities` and then the positional operator isn't matching?

**Schema**

```js
{

  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Title is required for Project"]
  },
                ...
  activities: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
                ...

      ]
    }
  ],

  createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}
```

Comment: whats the desired goal of your update? If you want to update ALL activity array, you can simply write `$set: { "activities.totalPointsPossible": 5 }`. Check the mongo manual for more infos: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: I want to update activities not equal to the given ObjectId("5e3e3c046e76599afe96d50f"). I updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing this part from the docs:

> If the query matches the array using a negation operator, such as $ne, $not, or $nin, then you cannot use the positional operator to update values from this array.
>
> However, if the negated portion of the query is inside of an $elemMatch expression, then you can use the positional operator to update this field.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#negations

Comment: I thought developers weren't supposed to read documentation.Thank you!

Comment: And probably this one as well https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_:  "the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the **first** element that matches the query"  Even without negation it won't update **all** subdocuments